# Query to Find Database Version WITH AS IF THEN?

Tags: sql-server-2008, liquibase

So a little background on our system to explain things.

Our databases are version (as probably most are). We have a table in the database called "DBVersion". However a few months ago we migrated over to liquibase. And now have a DATABASECHANGELOG table.

We, unfortunately, are a fairly unorganized company when it comes to our databases. So I am trying to write a view that will allow me to know what version our clients are on.

I honestly dont even know where to begin. But I figured I can write multiple CASE statements that will allow me to do this. I will be using the SP sp_msforeachdb to run the view.

```
SELECT 
Case when id = '8.12' then '8.12'
End as Version
From DATABASECHANGELOG
Where id = '8.12'
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
CASE 
    WHEN (SELECT ID FROM DATABASECHANGELOG WHERE ID = '8.12' IF NULL CONTINUE)
    WHEN (SELECT VERSION FROM DBVERSION, IF > 400 && < 425 THEN PRINT 'VERSION 8.7'
```

I know the above query isnt even in SQL, But It gives you an idea. Our versions with Liquibase are 8.10, 8.11, and 8.12 plus all future version. Everything below 8.10 is with the watson version which would be a simple number range.

Sorry if this is way too confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't really understand your question.

The following SQL displays your application's database versions:

```
SELECT ID,FILENAME,TAG  FROM DATABASECHANGELOG WHERE TAG IS NOT NULL
```

Each time you run the "tag" command it will insert a value into the tag column, so that a rollback operation knows how many changesets to undo.